# How to store data which contains quotes in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

In one of my forms I use the rich text editor from Yahoo!.
Now i want to store the data from that textarea in a MySQL database.

The user can enter anything in that textarea, e.g. many double or single quotes.

How can I store that data?

Normally we store by adding that data in one variable and then put that in sql, but the quotes cause problems.

Comment: I've edited this to make it more readable, but please learn to use the shift key.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You use a [PDO prepared statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457131/php-pdo-prepared-statements) (or [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php))

Comment: ... or MySQLi with prepared statements (I prefer PDO though)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).

> Escapes special characters in the
>   unescaped_string, taking into account
>   the current character set of the
>   connection so that it is safe to place
>   it in a mysql_query(). If binary data
>   is to be inserted, this function must
>   be used.
>
> mysql_real_escape_string() calls
>   MySQL's library function
>   mysql_real_escape_string, which
>   prepends backslashes to the following
>   characters: \x00, \n, \r, \, ', " and
>   \x1a.
>
> This function must always (with few
>   exceptions) be used to make data safe
>   before sending a query to MySQL.

e.g.

```
$value = mysql_real_escape_string(" ' \" etc ");
$sql = "INSERT INTO blah VALUES ('$value')";
```

But a better solution is to use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: ..."mysql_real_escape_string"
 is a MySQL function, not PHP.

Your example of:  
    $value = mysql_real_escape_string(" ' \" etc ");
would return PHP errors both for the unknown function, as well as the open-ended string.

Comment: @ashleedawg not sure I understand. I linked to the PHP documentation for the function. If it doesn't exist then the mysql module probably isn't loaded.

Answer (score 0):

If PDO isnt an option you might be able to use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead of course with a [prepared statement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).

Answer (score 0):

This is how my data as API response looks like, which I want to store in the MYSQL database. It contains Quotes, HTML Code , etc.

Example:-

```
{

rewardName: "Cabela's eGiftCard $25.00",

shortDescription: '<p>adidas gift cards can be redeemed in over 150 adidas Sport Performance, adidas Originals, or adidas Outlet stores in the US, as well as online at&nbsp;<a href="http://adidas.com/">adidas.com</a>.</p>

terms: '<p>adidas Gift Cards may be redeemed for merchandise on&nbsp;<a href="http://adidas.com/">adidas.com</a>&nbsp;and in adidas Sport Performance, adidas Originals, and adidas Outlet stores in the United States.'

}
```

SOLUTION

```
CREATE TABLE `brand` (
`reward_name` varchar(2048),
`short_description` varchar(2048),
`terms` varchar(2048),  
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

While inserting , In followed **JSON.stringify()**

```
    let brandDetails= {
    rewardName: JSON.stringify(obj.rewardName),  
    shortDescription: JSON.stringify(obj.shortDescription),
    term: JSON.stringify(obj.term),
     }
```

Above  is the JSON object and below is the SQL Query that insert data into MySQL.

```
let query = `INSERT INTO brand (reward_name, short_description, terms) 
VALUES (${brandDetails.rewardName}, 
(${brandDetails.shortDescription}, ${brandDetails.terms})`;
```

Its worked....

[image]

Answer (score -4):

Better yet! When submitting the content to the database, use addslashes();

When retrieving and displaying the string use stripslashes();

$string = "That's awesome!";

addslashes($string);
will come out as That\'s Awesome in the database (and won't break anything)

Then stripslashes($string);
will return it to normal.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php

I use this all the time - simple and straight-forward.

Comment: from http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php: " It's highly recommeneded to use DBMS specific escape function (e.g. mysqli_real_escape_string() for MySQL or pg_escape_string() for PostgreSQL) "

Answer (score -4):

Thanks you guys,
for your replay. 
But i had only replace the quotes characters...by this..

```
html = html.replace(/\'/g, "&#39;"); // 39 is ascii of single quotes
html = html.replace(/\"/g, "&#34;"); // 39 is ascii of double quotes
```

and then stored in the database. 
its working great..by this way...
and when i want that data then i just replace to its orginal.

But thanks for your replay..

---

Nitish.
[Panchjanya Corporation](http://www.panchjanyacorp.com)

Comment: This is JavaScript. You cannot do escaping like that on the client as this will leave your application open for sql injection if someone just disabled that script!