# How to sanitize simple _GET input from url to mysql in php

Tags: php, mysql, html, get, sanitization

I have a simple php script where hopefully people can simply go to something like `http://mydomain.com/get.php?id=TEXTMASH-1FD0066D-F75A-5D0C-6784-2FA0D055B0D7` and pull up this text block from my mysql db. I'm very new to php. Knowing that all of expected IDs should be something in the format of `TEXTMASH-1FD0066D-F75A-5D0C-6784-2FA0D055B0D7` how can I "sanitize" the _GET so it's not vulnerable to any attacks? I've looked at some guides but, i'm just not getting it. Anyone mind showing me? I'd really appreciate it.

```
<?php 

include_once("../../extern/dbinclude.php");

$id= $_GET['id'];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT text FROM mytable WHERE id='$id'")
or die(mysql_error());  

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

if($row)
{
echo nl2br($row['text']);
} else {
?>
<h2>Invalid URL</h2>
<?php
}
```

Comment: May I ask why you have such complicated IDs?  Why not just an INTeger?

Comment: Because there will eventually be a TON of entries, and actionscript has a really really simple UIDUtil.createUID() method.

Comment: define a TON? more than 4294967295?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could either use `mysql_real_escape_string` or possibly a regex to check the input. One possible regex for your case:

```
$pattern = '/^TEXTMASH-[0-9A-F]{8}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{12}$/';
if(!preg_match($pattern, $id))
{
    echo "No dice >:(";
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Nice. This definitely is a job for a regex, mostly to tell the legitimate user that the ID was not only not found, but was invalid (if you wish). No real need to escape with `mysql_real_escape_string` afterwards, but it won't hurt.

Comment: @Wesley: well it was more of an either / or thing.

Comment: I'm sure all the answers are valid, but this seems really simple to implement, gets the job done, and does a good job and making sure its a valid id thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Two main aspects to sanitizing the input:

1. Validate when you get it.  Check out the PHP [filter functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.filter.php) for doing validation.  In your case, the ID is rather complex, and you might need a custom validation function (using regex, possibly) for this.  However, I don't see why you're even using such a complex ID when you could use an INTeger ID, as is typical.
2. Use [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) or [prepared statements](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/4.1/prepared-statements.html) before inserting a user variable into the database.

And whenever you display a string variable, make sure to [escape](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) any HTML characters.

Answer (score 0):

By far the best way to do this is through prepared statements.  The other answers so far have suggested using `mysql_real_escape_string`, which works, but is easily missed by a developer and a PITA to have to use all the time.  Because it's so easy to miss and so hard to locate those errors, it's not a reliable or maintainable solution.

Prepared statements take this pain out of the process and automatically escape things appropriately.

You can find our more info elsewhere [on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457131/php-pdo-prepared-statements).