# Escaping backslashes in php no matter how many \ in string

Tags: php, mysql, escaping, addslashes

I'm very new to PHP. Currently,I'm facing one issue to escape \ and store in mysql DB.
eg., If the string is like `$str = \\aaaa\bbb\\\cccc$$` , I would like to save that string in DB . However, I don't know how to escape those backslashes. Please help me settle it.

Comment: Your code looks like that it has syntax errors.

Answer (score 2):

Your best option is to use prepared statements (e.g. through [PDO](http://php.net/PDO)):

```
$dbh = new PDO(…);
$sth = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO `yourtable` ( `column` ) VALUES ( :string )');
$sth->execute(array(':string' => '\\aaaa\bbb\\\cccc$$'));
```

Comment: Just a link to another question that may have some more useful information: [PHP PDO prepared statements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457131/php-pdo-prepared-statements)

Comment: Thank you.. I've tried that way and  '\aaaa\bbb\\cccc$$' is saved to DB rather than '\\aaaa\bbb\\\cccc$$' .

Comment: Are you sure? Single quotation marks don't interpret escape sequences and prepared statements store values ›as is‹. Maybe you are outputting them incorrectly?

Comment: Here's my codes $dbo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test4;","root","123");
$sql = 'INSERT INTO `table1` ( `name` ) VALUES ( :string )';
$sth = $dbo->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute(array(':string' => '\\aaaa\bbb\\\cccc$$'));

Comment: How do you verify what has been inserted into your db?

Comment: I go and see in mysql(phpadmin).