# mysql_real_escape_string removes the &-char

Tags: php, mysql-real-escape-string

I have a link: http://www.adress.com/Article.aspx?ID=262839&R=R1

After using mysql_real_escape_string on it, it changes to http://www.adress.com/Article.aspx?ID=262839

So it removes everything from the &-char: "&R=R1".

Why? And how can I fix this?

--- EDIT
Thanks for the answers. I will look in to the PDO.

And of course you were right, the problem is not caused by mysql_real_escape_string. The data is lost in my jquery ajax request.

```
$('.share').live('click', function(event) {
        var thesharelink = $(this);
        var thehref = $(this).attr('href');
        $(this).hide();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'edit.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: 'thehref=' + thehref,
            error: function(){
                $(thesharelink).replaceWith("Could not share");
            },
            contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8',
            success: function(result1) {
                $('body').append(result1);
                $(thesharelink).replaceWith(msg);
            }
        });
});
```

So once the data arrives to the php-file, it is lost. It seems like adding escape fixes the problem. Although I welcome any suggestions for improvement.

Comment: Are you sure ? its working for me

Comment: Please provide an example that reproduces the error.

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? Also, can you post some actual code? It's unlikely `mysql_real_escape_string` is the cause of this.

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string` does not do that, probably you've got some extra string manipulation function(s) applied to the string? Or, your varchar field is 44-symbols-length, e.g. varchar(44)... which would be odd

Comment: please, stop using the 10+ year old API and learn about prepared statements with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli).

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answers! Have much to learn. So my error is somewhere in my Jquery ajax request, and it seems like adding escape fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you switch to [PDO](http://no.php.net/pdo), and utilize prepared statements. Example usage (borrowed from [PHP PDO prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457131/php-pdo-prepared-statements)):

```
/* Execute a prepared statement by passing an array of values */
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name, colour, calories
    FROM fruit
    WHERE calories < ? AND colour = ?');

$sth->execute(array(150, 'red'));

$red = $sth->fetchAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

> So it removes everything from the &-char

It is not.

> how can I fix this?

Find the **real** cause for the & character removal.