# Having trouble getting my prepared statement to work

Tags: php, pdo

I have the following function :

```
function get_config($name = '')
{   
    $config = array();
    $row = array();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$GLOBALS['prefix']."config ";
    if ('' != $name) {$sql .= " WHERE name = '". $name ."'";}
    $result = $GLOBALS['conn']->query($sql);
    while ($row = $result->fetch()) {$config[$row['name']] = $row['value'];}
    if ('' != $name){return $config[$name];}
}
```

I use this to call all my site settings. I wanted to use prepared statements for this.

Here is what I did when I added the prepare statement:

```
function get_config($name = '')
{   
    $config = array();
    $row = array();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM config";
    if ('' != $name) {
    $sql .= " WHERE name = 'home'";
    }
    $result = $GLOBALS['conn']->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
    $result->execute(array(':name' => $name));
    while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
    $config[$row['name']] = $row['value'];
    }
    if ('' != $name) {
    return $config[$name];
    }
}
```

But now the function is not working. why is not working ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP PDO prepared statements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457131/php-pdo-prepared-statements)

Comment: If you are using this for a flat key:value configuration store, it might make sense to fetch all entries at once, and keep them in an array instead.

Comment: @mario what else can I do other than that? because that is what I am really trying to do, if there is a better way, tell me about it.

Comment: Make a `$prepvars = array()` and only add `[":name"] = $name` in the `if` condition. Then use `$prepvars` for the `->execute()` call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Migrating my answer from the (now removed) [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15057241/pdo-prepare-stopped-the-function-from-working).

You're executing the statement with a `:name` placeholder, but it's not there in the query itself:

```
function get_config($name = 'home')
{   
    $config = array();
    $row = array();
    $sql = "SELECT value FROM config WHERE name = :name";

    $result = $GLOBALS['conn']->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
    $result->execute(array(
        ':name' => $name
    ));

    return array(
        $name => current($result->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0))
    );
}
```

**What changed**

The two main changes:

```
function get_config($name = 'home')
```

When the function is called without parameters, `$name` defaults to `'home'`.

```
return current($result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0));
```

The `fetchAll()` returns an array with only the first column in each array entry. Applying `current()` on that either returns the first (and only) array entry or `false` if the array is empty.

**Caution**

Using database handles from `$GLOBALS` is not recommended; it would be better to either pass the instance in `get_config()` or let `get_config()` be a method in a class that receives as the database handle in their constructor.

Comment: it would be great if you can explain Those two lines :         `':name' => $name ?: 'home'` and `current($result->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0));`

Comment: for some reason, I am only getting the first letter of the result.. what can it be the problem?

Comment: @shnisaka What does `print_r($result->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0))` give then?

Comment: whenever I change it with `current()` it gives me the first letter.. in this case "h"

Comment: @shnisaka Well, `current()` on that should just give `http://www.example.com`. [Proof](http://codepad.viper-7.com/X5W4fm). If not, the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25055/discussion-between-shnisaka-and-jack)