# MYSQL/PHP Syntax Error

Tags: php, mysql, syntax

Here is that php code that is at the top of my page:

```
if(!$_SESSION['username']){
  header("Location: ../error.php?id=1");
}

$teamgamertag = $_POST["gamertag"];
$teamgame = $_POST["game"];
$teamtype = $_POST["type"];
$teamname = $_POST["name"];
$teamconsole = $_POST["console"];

if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
  $sql2 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO teams (name, game, players, creator, console, leaders, type, score) VALUES ('$teamname', '$teamgame', '$teamgamertag', '$teamgamertag', '$teamconsole', '$teamgamertag', '$teamtype', '0'") or die(mysql_error());

  if($sql2){
    header("../results.php?id=1");
  }else{
    exit();
  }
}
?>
```

I dont know what the problem is and where to fix it. Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: There's no obvious syntax error here, except for the missing opening `<?php` tag. Most likely your problem in `undefined index: gamertag` or something like that because you haven't checked to make sure they are set before trying to use them.

Comment: @NicholasPickering it's in the SQL missing `)`

Comment: your second header isn't in the correct format

Comment: This, is a perfect example of "not a real question".

Comment: Also, from manual [`header()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) `HTTP/1.1 requires an absolute URI as argument to » Location: including the scheme, hostname and absolute path,` - ie. `header("Location: http://$host.$uri");`

Answer (score 4):

Your SQL query's ending parenthesis is missing:

```
'$teamgamertag', '$teamtype', '0'")
```

It should be here:

```
'$teamgamertag', '$teamtype', '0')")
```

Also, your SQL is vulnerable to injection. Don't make query strings manually. Use prepared statements: [PHP PDO prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457131/php-pdo-prepared-statements)

Comment: Actually, there should be two parentheses, I think. `'0')")` the first one closing the VALUES block and the second one closing the call to `mysql_query`.

Comment: I was going to do the prepared statements later, I just wanted to get this priority setup. Also, when I make your change, I get an error loading the page...
"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in /home/u914842696/public_html/onlinegw/teams/create.php on line 17"

Comment: @user2203989 use the updated code in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code as

```
<?php
if(!$_SESSION['username']){
  header("Location: ../error.php?id=1");
}

$teamgamertag = $_POST["gamertag"];
$teamgame = $_POST["game"];
$teamtype = $_POST["type"];
$teamname = $_POST["name"];
$teamconsole = $_POST["console"];

if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
  $sql2 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO teams (name, game, players, creator, console, leaders, type, score) VALUES ('$teamname', '$teamgame', '$teamgamertag', '$teamgamertag', '$teamconsole', '$teamgamertag', '$teamtype', '0')") or die(mysql_error());

  if($sql2){
    header('Location: ../results.php?id=1');
  }else{
    exit();
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: you are missing a `;` at the end of `header('Location: ../results.php?id=1')`

Comment: Thank you. I didn't noticed @sean