# How to I retrieve data from a mysql table cell and put it into a variable in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a function that will retrieve an id number from a table with multiple columns, put it in a variable which i want to use to send as a "claims number" in an email to a claimant and also echo on a confirmation screen. Here's what I have so far.

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM warranty_claim where lname=$lname";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$claim_id = $result;
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection; also mysql_* suite of functions are deprecated.  Consider using mysqli or PDO - this SO article can assist you further:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457131/php-pdo-prepared-statements

Comment: mysql_query returns a result handle. you need to fetch a row from that handle, which will contain the per-row data.

Comment: I'm vulnerable? I don't know much about that, how would I protect it?

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($sql));

$claim_id = $result['id'];
```

Comment: The shortest and the most simplistic approach. This definitely deserves an upvote. Don't ignore other comments that recommend you switch to PDO and MySQLi though.

Comment: @ColorWP.com I figured there was enough rants about PDO and MySQLi about the place that someone clearly new to database programming didn't need an ear bashing :)

Yet... :)

Answer (score 1):

Supposing you are sure that you will receive 1 row.

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM warranty_claim where lname=$lname";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$c = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$claim_id = $c['lname'];
```

NB*: And get ready for a lecture. Someone is going to tell you that mysql is depracated.
Start using MySQLi or PDO (recommended).

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM warranty_claim where lname=$lname";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
$claim_id = $row[0];
```

or

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM warranty_claim where lname=$lname";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
   $claim_id = $row['id'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);`

`$claim_id = $row['id'];`

please note that you should also check for errors (e.g. `if($result === FALSE)`). Also, there are other ways to fetch data - I recommend looking at [mysql_fetch_array](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-fetch-array.php), [mysql_fetch_row](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-fetch-row.php), [mysql_fetch_assoc](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) and [mysql_fetch_object](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-fetch-object.php)

Also, don't rely on the statement always returning exactly one row - make sure that the result is as expected: [mysql_num_rows](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-num-rows.php)

Answer (score -1):

Give this a try:

```
$sql        = "SELECT id FROM warranty_claim where lname='".$lname."'";
$result     = mysql_query($sql);
$objResult  = mysql_fetch_array($result);  
$claim_id   = $objResult['id'];
```

Comment: $result won't allow access to information in the resource. One of the mysql result functions need to be used.

Comment: @ScottMorrison Great I could help! Would you mind giving my answer an upvote since you cant accept it yet?

Comment: I just tried but it says it requires a 5 reputation. Not sure what to do now.