# Approve users from table - check box

Tags: php

I'm writing an php script to approve users that registered on my page, but i'm facing a little problem when i want to approve them. Here's as far as i could get.

Table:

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("activation") or die(mysql_error());
//User Approval Script
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM userinfo WHERE status='0'") 
or die(mysql_error());
echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr> <th>Name</th> <th>Action</th> <th>Hours</th> <th>Approve</th> </tr>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result2 )) {
 // Print out the contents of each row into a table
 echo "<tr><td>"; 
 echo $row['first_name'];
 echo "</td><td>"; 
 echo $row['last_name'];
 echo "</td>"; 
 echo "<td>"; 
 echo $row['email'];
 echo "</td><td>";
 echo "<form action=\"approve.php\" method=\"post\"><input name=\"approve[]\" type=\"checkbox\">";
 echo "</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Approve\"></form>";
?>
```

approve.php

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("activation") or die(mysql_error());
$ticked = $_POST['approve'];

foreach($ticked as $id) {
     mysql_query("UPDATE status SET approved = '1' WHERE `ID` = '$id'");
}
unset($id);  
?>
```

I would also like to know how i can send email to each user that is approved...

Thanks in advance everyone!

Edit:

The page on approve.php is all blank, and status isn't getting updated.

Comment: And what's your problem? Be specific please.

Comment: Your code is very vunerable to SQL Injection. See [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174) and [Why shouldn't I use mysql\_\* functions in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942).

Comment: use PHP `mail()` function - Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this, Moved `<form>` tag from near checkbox into top and added checkbox value with `$row["id"]`

```
<?php
        mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db("activation") or die(mysql_error());
        //User Approval Script
        $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM userinfo WHERE status='0'") 
        or die(mysql_error());
        echo "<form action=\"approve.php\" method=\"post\"><table border='1'>";
        echo "<tr> <th>Name</th> <th>Action</th> <th>Hours</th> <th>Approve</th> </tr>";
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result2 )) {
         // Print out the contents of each row into a table
         echo "<tr><td>"; 
         echo $row['first_name'];
         echo "</td><td>"; 
         echo $row['last_name'];
         echo "</td>"; 
         echo "<td>"; 
         echo $row['email'];
         echo "</td><td>";
         echo "<input name=\"approve[]\" type=\"checkbox\" value='".$row["id"]."' >";
         echo "</td></tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
        echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Approve\"></form>";
?>
```

In approve.php,

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("activation") or die(mysql_error());
    $ticked = $_POST['approve'];

    foreach($ticked as $id) {
         mysql_query("UPDATE status SET approved = '1' WHERE `ID` = '$id'");

         $message ='Approved message';

         mail('to email address', 'Your Subject', $message);
    }

 ?>
```

**Note:** Use mysqli_* functions or PDO instaed of using mysql_* functions (deprecated)

Answer (score 0):

You tried to open form in loop `while` and missed attribute `value` in checkbox.

**Change**

```
echo "<form action=\"approve.php\" method=\"post\"><input name=\"approve[]\" type=\"checkbox\">";
```

**To**

```
echo '<input name="approve" type="checkbox" value='.$row["id"].'>';
```

Then put `echo "<form action ='approve.php' method='post'>";` above `while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result2 )) {`

Answer (score -1):

You should have one large form, with many checkboxes (I imagine that's what your second page is based upon), but checkboxes are `<input>`s, not `<form>`s. Your final HTML should look something like:

```
<form>
    <table>
    ...
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="approve[]" value="USERIDTHATYOUWANTTOAPPROVE"></td>
    ...
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="approve[]" value="OTHERUSERIDTHATYOUWANTTOAPPROVE"></td>
    ...
    </table>
</form>
```

### Also!

- Your code is very susceptible to SQL Injection. See [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174) and [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942).
- You should use **[prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457131/php-pdo-prepared-statements)** to offload work in your code (you only send the query once, and change the parameters each time).