# Saving data to database from textarea

Tags: php, html, mysql, textarea

I am a newbie in PHP. I just want to know why every time I save a string data from textarea it's always having the `<p> string </p>` format inserted in the database. This is my code:

```
 <table>
  <tr>
   <td>  
    <textarea name="event_desc" cols="40" rows="10" id="event_desc"></textarea>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="Add" id="Add" value="Add event" /></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

And everytime i include a single quotation `(')`, it always appears as `" & #39;"` without space.This is the sample output:

```
input: test2 ' (and every space i made count)
<p>    test2 &#39; &nbsp;&nbsp; $</p>
```

I already use mysql_real_escape_string, addslashes and stripslashes.

This is my code in saving into database:

```
 <?php 
 if(isset($_REQUEST['Add']))
 { 
  $event_title=$_POST['event_title'];                                                                         $event_desc=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['event_desc']);
  $section=$_POST['section'];
  $get_date=NOW;
  if($event_title=="" || $event_desc=="")
  {
    echo'<div class="warning">Some of the fields are empty.</div>';
  }
  else
  {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO events (`event_title`, `event_desc`,`event_date`,`event_target`) VALUE('$event_title','$event_desc','$get_date','$section')") or die(mysql_error('Error: Error in adding entries'));
    echo'<div class="success">You have just added 1 event for School. You will be redirect in  5 seconds</div>';
    echo "<META HTTP-EQUIV='Refresh' CONTENT='5; URL=events.php'>";
  }
 }
 ?>
```

Thanks you guys for the help.

Comment: what is your way to connect to db? are you using mysql or mysqli or pdo?

Comment: i use mysql Sir @Kiyarash

Answer (score 2):

my suggestion will be to use **mysqli::real_escape_string**  with [prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457131/php-pdo-prepared-statements)
click [mysqli::real_escape_string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `addslashes()` while storing into db and use to retrive if it is encoded `htmlspecialchars_decode`

```
 <?php
$str = "<p>this -&gt; &quot;</p>\n";

echo htmlspecialchars_decode($str);

// note that here the quotes aren't converted
echo htmlspecialchars_decode($str, ENT_NOQUOTES);
?>
```

OUTPUT:

```
<p>this -> "</p>
<p>this -> &quot;</p>
```

Ref: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php

Answer (score 0):

Other than traditional methods mention above.

We can encode string coming from text area using "base64_encode" and then store in db...While retrieving  from db decode it back using "base64_decode" function.

Note:- As per document it consume 33% more space.

Ref:- http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php

Answer (score -2):

Your saving html encoded text to your database.  Punctuation are encoded when viewing in a page.  So you have to decode them some how.  I'm not a PHP person, but I know this is your problem.