# $_POST unknown amount of elements

Tags: php, html, mysql, post

My idea is like an basket on a webshop.

I have a list of items filled into a form by php like:

```
<?php while($info=msqli_fetch_array($query)){  ?>
    <Input type="text" id="someid1" value="<?php echo $info['info']; ?>"> 
    <Input type="Checkbox" id="checkid1" value="1">
    <Input type="Checkbox" id="checkid2" value="2">
<?php } ?>
```

I want to use POST for submitting. 
on the next page for each line should be done this:

MYSQLI query

```
INSERT into booking (text,variable1,variable2) 
  VALUES ('$_POST['someid1']','$_POST['checkid1']','$_POST['checkid2']';
```

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: Prevent yourself from mysql-injection by using mysqli_* or PDO methods. Furthermore you should use the name attribute with array annotation. So you can loop over it after submit.

Comment: @HKK You should use prepared statements.

Answer (score 3):

You can setup named inputs with brackets to get the results as an array server-side. For example:

```
<input type="text" name="fruits[1]" value="apple" />
<input type="text" name="fruits[2]" value="orange" />
```

on server side:

```
<?php
print_r($_POST['fruits']);
?>

array(
  1 => 'apple',
  2 => 'orange',
)
```

That solves the question. But your code suggests something else that should really be addressed.

You're asking for SQL injection if you just dump `$_POST` variables into a query. Use PHP's PDO functionality and parameterize your input. Look at the 2nd example in the answer at [PHP PDO prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457131/php-pdo-prepared-statements) for more info.

Comment: The idea is to view a basket with articles, where you can edit the article-text and select from 3 checkboxes from wich warehouse the article should be shipped, and than insert the line in a table (SQL)

Comment: could you maybe Show how this code can be done in the normal php version, not the one with "=>" i dont get that version.

Comment: what do you mean by 'normal PHP version'? => is completely normal syntax for arrays

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [foreach](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) but IMHO isn't a very secure thing what you want to do.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using array annotation in form elements. I think not handling / sanitizing the data on the server would be the only concern.

Comment: I didn' say it was wrong, I use it. But I sanitize the data first before save it to the dddbb.
Btw, I don't know why is the down vote. With a foreach it can be done what he asked for, but ain't gonna code it for him.

Answer (score -1):

You should use arrays in your html, then you get the corresponding arrays in your `$_POST` array. Note that you need the name attribute:

```
<input name="someid[<?php echo $info['id']; ?>]" id="someid1" value="<?php echo $info['info']; ?>">
<input name="checkid[<?php echo $info['id']; ?>]" id="checkid1" value="1">
// etc.
```

Now `$_POST['someid']`, etc. will be arrays you can loop over.

Note that you need to use prepared statements to store the information in your database.

Comment: @HKK `foreach ($_POST['someid'] as $key => $value)` where `$key` matches the `$info['id']` of the previous page.