# Convert MySQL to PDO - Query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have a query I wish to convert to be using `PDO` instead of `mysql_`:

```
$checkLikes = $sdb->query(sprintf("SELECT * FROM `likes`,`users`
                                  WHERE `likes`.`by` = `users`.`idu` 
                                  AND `likes`.`by` IN (%s) 
                                  ORDER BY `id` DESC 
                                  LIMIT %s", $subscriptions, 25));
```

The above query is using MySQL to get executed. I am trying to convert it to PDO:

```
$checkLikes = $sdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM `likes`,`users` 
                             WHERE `likes`.`by` = `users`.`idu` 
                             AND `likes`.`by` IN :subscriptions 
                             ORDER BY `id` DESC 
                             LIMIT :subscriptions", $subscriptions, 25);
$checkLikes->bindParam(":subscriptions",$subscriptions);
$checkLikes->execute();
```

The above code doesn't work, as I get these errors:

```
Warning: PDO::prepare() expects at most 2 parameters, 3 given in /home/user/public_html/header.php on line 411

Fatal error: Call to a member function bindParam() on a non-object in /home/user/public_html/header.php on line 412
```

What am I doing wrong? I've used `bindParam()` to bind the variable to the PDO query. I can't see the error.

Comment: What is not clear here?? `PDO::prepare() expects at most 2 parameters, 3 given` see the documentation, you'll understand.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457131/php-pdo-prepared-statements

Comment: I have only given one?

Comment: No, `3 given` means `You gave 3`! Only need 1 in your case which is the query. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First remove the second and third parameter you are sending to the `->prepare` statement as only the query is needed:

```
$checkLikes = $sdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM `likes`,`users` WHERE `likes`.`by` = `users`.`idu` AND `likes`.`by` IN (:subscriptions) ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT :subscriptions_limit");
```

Then bind your two parameters and execute the query:

```
$checkLikes->bindParam(":subscriptions",$subscriptions, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$subscription_limit = 25;
$checkLikes->bindParam(":subscriptions_limit",$subscription_limit, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$checkLikes->execute();
```

and since you are using an `IN` you should also make sure that `$subscriptions` is a `string` representation of the array values and not an `array` in `bindParam()`

Comment: Beat me to clicking the posting button by ~2 seconds. +1

Comment: This gives me: Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference in 413 (The second bindParam())

Comment: `bindParam` binds the parameter as a `reference` so we cannot specify the value directly, I updated the answer so that the value is passed through a variable `$subscription_limit`.

Comment: Ah, ok got it! But the query has an error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''11,13' ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 25' at line 1' in

Comment: That's probably because you are giving `$subscriptions` as an array i presume, since it is not shown in your code

Comment: $subscriptions are printed out like this: return implode(',', $subscriptions);

Comment: Updated the answer so that the query now has `IN (:subscriptions)` since your string doesn't have `parenthesis` after the IN and tries to execute `IN 1,2,3` instead of `IN (1,2,3)`

Comment: Problem with this answer is, that it won't work for a `WHERE ... IN ()` clause if you're using prepared (and not emulated) statements.