# My PDO fetch returns "array" instead of number of points

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, fetch

I'm trying to get this PDO fetch to display the number of points a user has.
However, I simply just get the output "array". What have I done wrong here, and is there an easier way to fetch a single row from a column than this?

```
// CONNECT TO DATABASE
require 'database.php';

// FETCH POINTS
$usernamedb = $_SESSION['user'];
echo $usernamedb;

$fetchpoints = $db->prepare("SELECT points FROM login WHERE username = '$usernamedb'");
$fetchpoints->execute();

$pointsfetched = $fetchpoints->fetchAll();
echo $pointsfetched;
```

Comment: pdo prepare - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457131/php-pdo-prepared-statements

Comment: Since you're already using PDO, you could also adopt prepared statements now. Use `->prepare("SELECT .. WHERE x = ?")` and `->execute(array($usernamedb));` for binding the `?` placeholder. (Just because your string originates in a session, doesn't ensure it's implicitly constrained. Better safe than sorry!)

Comment: How have you gotten to the point where you have a working website in PHP using a database connection while not knowing (and apparently not being able to find out) how to read a value from an array?

Comment: I used to just do it like I typed it now, but for some reason it didn't work this time... I'm not sure what I have done differently..

Comment: Here is the code I got: http://www.codeshare.io/EBwU6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want a single value out of the query, then don't use [`fetchAll()`](http://php.net/pdostatement.fetchAll) to get an array/list.

```
$pointsfetched = $fetchpoints->fetchObject()->points;
```

Is often the most concise option.
([`fetch`](http://php.net/pdostatement.fetch) and [`fetchObject`](http://php.net/pdostatement.fetchObject) just pull a single row from the result set.)

Comment: This worked for me, thank you :) I dont know why I couldn't use the same method as I used before... has there been any updates recently?

Comment: I have another question @mario, why doesn't this work?`$usernamedb = $_SESSION['user'];
            $fetchone = $db->prepare("SELECT profilepicture,name,points FROM login WHERE username = '$usernamedb'");
            $personalprofile = $fetchone->fetchAll();

            echo "<img src='";
            echo $personalprofile[0]['profilepicture'];`

Comment: That code and the array access actually look ok. What does `print_r()` tell about the result list, and how does the resulting HTML output look (`view source`, there's no closing `'>` img tag end)?

Comment: print_r() gives me nothing, I have the closing tag, just didn't add it with :) I just get <img src> in the view source

Comment: Then probe the `$usernamedb` instead. Possibly not set (session_start missing etc.), resulting in a failing query and absent values.

Answer (score 1):

All calls to `PDO::fetch` or `PDO::fetchAll` will return an array.  If you only want to get one column from the first row, you need to use [`PDO::fetchColumn`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php)

```
//Use 0 to get the first column
$pointsfetched = $fetchpoints->fetchColumn(0);
```

`PDO::fetch` will always return an array of the next row. (or false)

`PDO::fetchAll` will always return an array of row arrays. (or false)

Answer (score 0):

Start by changing:

```
echo $pointsfetched;
```

to:

```
echo json_encode($pointsfetched);
```

This will show you the data you have fetched in JSON format, if it is working. You can then use something like:

```
foreach ($pointsfetched as $point) {
    echo $point;
}
```

to display all the points.

Comment: This just made me get `d[{"points":"12524","0":"12524"}]`. I am simply looking to get 12524 from this.

Answer (score 0):

Change 
    $fetchpoints->fetchAll()
to
    $fetchpoints->fetchColumn()

This way you'll only get the first point as a typed var instead of an array of one point

Comment: It was fetchColumn, sorry