# insert ip into mysql php from $GET

Tags: php, mysql, get

Hi I am trying to insert data into a db and I am getting an error when it gets to the IP address, it seems the decimal places in the ip are causing the error.

> INSERT INTO farms (name, ip, amount) VALUES (somename, 123.32.32.1,
>   432432) SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You
>   have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.32.1,
>   432432)' at line 2

```
$servername = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
$dbname = 'myDB';
$table = 'myTable';

$name = $_GET['name'];
$ip = $_GET['ip'];
$amount = $_GET['amount'];

    try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO $table (name, ip, amount)
    VALUES ($name, $ip, $amount)";
    $conn->exec($sql);
    echo "New record created successfully";
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
    }

$conn = null;
```

Comment: please add the 'farms' table structure, your IP field needs to be a VARCHAR or TEXT, maybe its an INT or NUMBER and of course it will not work...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP PDO prepared statements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457131/php-pdo-prepared-statements)

Comment: Quotes.  Just... Quotes.

Comment: You have many issues. For SQL alone, strings need to be quoted. Once that is fixed you are open to SQL injections. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Use parameterized queries.  That would fix your problems.  Using quotes is just a band-aid.

Comment: what's the type of ip ? can you provide the design of table ?

Comment: Thanks guys this is my table structure, also I dont need security as this will only stay on my local machine
name varchar(20)
ip varchar(15)
amount int(20)

Comment: also I have tried "" to '' and vise-versa with no difference

Comment: How is this a duplicate of that post Machavity?

Comment: Did you read the accepted answer? That's how you should do this instead of passing the values directly

Comment: So how would I write my example like that? It is really hard for me to understand that.

Comment: Machavity I am asking what is breaking in my code not your opinion on a better way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO $table (name, ip, amount)
    VALUES ('$name', '$ip', $amount)";
```

You missed quotes for char/varchar.That may be the problem