# PDO MySQL handling apostrophe (') in names

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, apostrophe

I'm getting problems with my PDO query as soon as there is an apostrophe inside the name I'm looking for, like `D'Angelo`. Names without (') inside the name are working fine.

```
try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname",$config['DB_USERNAME'],$config['DB_PASSWORD']); 
    foreach($dbh->query("SELECT * from position WHERE spieler='$playername'") as $row) {
        echo ''.$row['pos'].'</td></tr>';
    }
    $dbh = null;
} 
catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}
```

Update:

So, with all the help and hints to prepared statements I was able to get this finally to work.

```
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname",$config['DB_USERNAME'],$config['DB_PASSWORD']);
                $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * from position WHERE spieler=:player1");
                $stmt->execute(array(":player1" => $player1));
                foreach ($stmt as $row) {
                echo ''.$row['pos'].'</td></tr>';
    }
    $dbh = null;
```

Comment: Use prepared statements and it will solve this problem.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. You should use [mysqli](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [PDO](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) prepared statements with bound parameters as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP PDO prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457131/php-pdo-prepared-statements)

Answer (score 3):

That's because when you have a name with a `'` in it, your query looks like this:

```
"SELECT * from position WHERE spieler='D'Angelo'"
```

which is invalid so $dbh->query is returning false, which is an invalid argument for foreach. To make a quick fix, you need to change the query from

```
"SELECT * from position WHERE spieler='$playername'"
```

to

```
"SELECT * from position WHERE spieler='" . addslashes($playername) . "'"
```

which will give you

```
"SELECT * from position WHERE spieler='D\'Angelo'"
```

As has been pointed out, you'd do better with prepared statements:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * from position WHERE spieler=:playername"
$stmt->execute(array(':playername' => $playername));
while ($row = $dbh->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo ''.$row['pos'].'</td></tr>';
}
```

Comment: Your `prepare()` shouldn't have the $ in playername.

Comment: It can be difficult as unless you can actually run the code, you don't always notice the slight flaws in it.

Comment: @NigelRen as was proved by my just noticing another stupid mistake! :(

Answer (score 1):

You should use prepared statement.

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * from position WHERE spieler= :playername")

if(isset($playername))
{
   $stmt->bindParam(":playername", $playername);
}

$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Wouldn't you halt the entire query block if not set?  Why not put the data in the execute call and save the function call?

Comment: @mickmackusa Yes you're right. To be honest I did a copy past of a prepared statement which included a condition encompassing `$stmt`