# php use '' in a query without convert the value to a pointer

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement

I need to execute a sql query where I need to use a apostrophe because I search for an email address. When I now type the `''` in the query they become a variable pointer but they should just tell mysql that this is a string.

How can I tell the program to use them in a different way? I already tried `pdo->quote`.

```
$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT user_id FROM tbl_server WHERE user_id = (SELECT user_id from tbl_user where Email = ':email') "); // here i need the normal apostrophe
$result = $statement->execute(array('email' => $email));
$user = $statement->fetch();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP PDO prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457131/php-pdo-prepared-statements)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must not quote `:email` in the query; the database driver will determine how to handle the parameter because it knows the passed type and the column's type in the database. But you need to prepend the `:` to `email` when executing the parameterized query.

```
$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT user_id FROM tbl_server WHERE user_id = (SELECT user_id from tbl_user where Email = :email) "); // here i need the normal apostrophe
$result = $statement->execute(array(':email' => $email));
$user = $statement->fetch();
```

By the way you should check whether `$result` is `true` or `false`, also your query might deliver an empty result set. So you should check whether `$user === false` (i.e. no user found) after fetching.